# Organizing large amounts of application configuration in Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring-cloud

Now that Spring Cloud Config is GA we're looking at using it as our external configuration source for our Spring Boot applications. Because the technologies involved are so new to our organization, I'm getting a lot of questions as to how Cloud Config will work in production, especially around deployment and disaster scenarios.

I think I'm starting to get a handle as to how the server loads up and distributes config, which is leading me to ask what the best way to organize and deploy configuration is. My first thought was that I'd have each application get its own Git repo as well as a common configuration repo.

The problem here is that I've been misreading the documentation. I was under the impression that I could do something like this:

```
git:
   uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/common-config.git
   repos:
      app-config:
         uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/
         pattern: app*-config.git
```

With the idea that the app-config piece would pick up all Git repositories that matched the pattern. As we deployed new applications we'd restart the servers to pick up the configuration in the new repositories. What I wasn't getting was that pattern refers to the files within the specified repository, not the git files themselves. So what I'd really have to do is something like this:

```
git:
   uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/common-config.git
   repos:
      app-foo-config:
         uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/app-foo-config.git
         pattern: app-foo*
```

My problem with this approach is that every time I deploy another application I'm going to need a process to update the Cloud Config Servers' bootstrap.yml files, in addition to restarting them, to add another application's repo, like so:

```
git:
   uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/common-config.git
   repos:
      app-foo-config:
         uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/app-foo-config.git
         pattern: app-foo*    
      app-bar-config:
         uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/app-bar-config.git
         pattern: app-bar*
```

This isn’t really ideal. To me, it looks like I’ll have to have my config broken out into several repositories by domain, which gives me something like this:

```
git:
   uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/common-config.git
   repos:
      domain-foo-config:
         uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/domain-foo-config.git
         pattern: domain-foo*    
      domain-bar-config:
         uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/domain-bar-config.git
         pattern: domain-bar*    
      domain-baz-config:
         uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/domain-baz-config.git
         pattern: domain-baz*
```

This should keep my config from getting too out of control as long as I can keep the domains logical. So, what are my questions? There’s two:

1. Is my final approach a reasonable one or is there a better way that I’m missing?
2. The docs imply that config can be in folders and that would help keep the config organized. Has anyone had any luck with that?

Also, since you’ve come this far into my wall of text, I think patterns are bugged for multiple repo configurations.

Without a pattern the server doesn’t deliver any configuration from any of the files in the repo. On top of that while pattern: “*” works, it only works for first repo. After that, the Cloud Config Server cannot load any configuration from any file in any other repo no matter what pattern is given. This includes the default repo.

Comment: Bugs go here please: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config (but I don't think it's a bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Without a pattern the server doesn’t deliver any configuration from
>   any of the files in the repo. On top of that while pattern: “*” works,
>   it only works for first repo. After that, the Cloud Config Server
>   cannot load any configuration from any file in any other repo no
>   matter what pattern is given. This includes the default repo.

If you don't need the pattern, you can simply using the

```
git:
   uri: ssh://git@stash:7999/scc/common-config.git
```

If you need to use the repo with pattern, make sure your application's spring.application.name in bootstrap.yml has the same pattern.  For example,

```
spring:
   application:
      name: domain-foo-app-a
```